# What is the Asp.NET Core library for Micosoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory to implement Azure Active Directory?

Tags: cors, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I noticed a lot of `Owin.Security` stuff are in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` namespace.

Like

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
```

But for the equivalent of the `Micosoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory` in traditional ASP.NET, a package named `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ActiveDirectory` is actually not from Microsoft, but from some **OneBitSoftware**. Hosted [here](https://github.com/OneBitSoftware/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ActiveDirectory).

I am curious if the `ActiveDirectory` namespace has been renamed into `JwtBearer` or `OpenIdConnect` or `OAuth`. But none seems to work with AzureAD like this:

```
var options = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Tenant = ...
}
```

I was trying to use **AzureAD** for authentication, without `ActiveDirectory`, which NuGet package am I supposed to use?

---

## Update

The examples in [ASP.NET docs site](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/azure-active-directory/index.html) are rather old. Packages like

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OAuthBearer": "1.0.0-beta3",
```

is no longer in use for latest Asp.net core.

Comment: may help https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/azure-active-directory/index.html

Comment: You should be able to use JwtBearer as the replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tratcher pointed out the right direction in the question comment section.

So I wrote an extension method to use Azure AD.

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
{
    public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseAzureADBearerAuthentication(
            this IApplicationBuilder app,
            IConfigurationRoot configuration)
        {
            var tenant = configuration.GetSection("AzureAD:Tenant").Value;
            var azureADInstance = configuration.GetSection("AzureAD:AzureADInstance").Value;
            var audience = configuration.GetSection("AzureAD:Audience").Value;
            var authority = $"{azureADInstance}{tenant}";


            var jwtBearerAuthOptions = new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                Audience = audience,
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                Authority = authority
            };
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtBearerAuthOptions);
            return app;
        }
    }
}
```

That extension method on `IApplicationBuilder` is put into the namespace of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder`.

In **Startup.cs**

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod());
app.UseAzureADBearerAuthentication(Configuration);
app.UseMvc();
```

The settings are stored in **appsettings.json** like this:

```
"AzureAD": {
  "AzureADInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Tenant": "{my AD}",
  "Audience": "{my application registered in AD}"
}
```

The NuGet package for JwtBearer is

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
```

Comment: That's excellent - I took the liberty of wrapping this into a NuGet package so other people can use it as given directly: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureADBearerAuthentication/